# Taking gridview value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to save student ID which is being set in a GridView. I want to save each row student ID into table through model whose object name is "am".

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{              
   am.Std_ID= GridView1.Rows[i]["Std_ID"]; 
}
```

By using above method it says you cannot use indexing with GridView. What should I do.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FullName" HeaderText="Student Names"/>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign = "Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox  runat="server" ID="marks" Width="30px" ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My second question is in  ItemTemplate I am using textbox. When I use its ID in function then Visual Studio says "marks doesn't exist in the current context". What should I do?

Comment: Not clear with your requirement..!

Comment: You could use a  `HiddenField` to store the `Std_ID`. Then you get it in the loop via `((HiddenField)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("HiddenFieldID")).Value`

Answer (score 0):

This will not exist: -

```
GridView1.Rows[i]["Std_ID"];
```

You don't access the data bound to a grid in this way; you need to reference the DataItem property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem(v=vs.110).aspx

However your requirement is quite common, you could add a HiddenField control to the itemtemplate to store your ID, and retrieve  the control (and therefore its value) in a server-side method.